# map() and anonymous functions

Tags: r, purrr, anonymous-function, quantmod

Can anyone explain the syntax of get(.) here? getSymbols() is from the quantmod package.

```
prices <-
  getSymbols(symbols,
             src = 'yahoo',
             from = "2012-12-31",
             to = "2017-12-31",
             auto.assign = TRUE,
             warnings = FALSE) %>%
  map(~Ad(get(.)))
```

I understand that get() can be used to generate an object from its name. I also understand that purrr::map() can be used with an anonymous function like this

```
mylist %>% map(~ . *2)
```

but I don't understand the syntax where the dot goes inside get() and whether

```
~Ad(get(.))
```

is being used as an anonymous function.
As far as I understood the syntax for that is with a tilda and then a dot.

```
map(~ . *2)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's use "INTC" for the value in symbol.

`getSymbols` with `auto.assign = TRUE` will place the data retrieved in the global environment. The symbol value is used as the placeholder for x, not the INTC xts object. So when you get to the `map` section, the `.` is filled in with "INTC" from symbol, not the xts object. `get(.)` will retrieve the xts object from the global environment, based on the value in symbol which in turn makes the `Ad` function work and will extract the adjusted price from the INTC xts object and store this in the prices object.

If you have multiple symbols, prices will contain all the adjusted prices in a list per symbol, but it will not be a named list.